# Getting error when going to profile for internal jdbc User store wso2 5.10.0 Pirmary, with secondary Active directory store

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.stub.UserProfileMgtServiceUserProfileExceptionException: UserProfileMgtServiceUserProfileExceptionException

[-1234] [2020-04-14 21:31:12,382] [ab3af6fb-69bc-44fd-8cb5-46cb06dd3cc4] INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=MASONITE/admin@carbon.super Action=Get-User-List Target=null Data={"Claim Value":"d939fee0-7cc5-11ea-ad7e-42010af00727","Claim":"http://wso2.org/claims/userid"} Outcome=Failure Error={"Error Message":"Un-expected error while getting user list, Error occurred while getting user list from property : scimId & value : d939fee0-7cc5-11ea-ad7e-42010af00727 & profile name : null","Error Code":"34003"}

on the screen it then shows
Error while loading user profile metadata

Steps:
Go into the carbon console and click on the user to get it show the profile. This only happens when i add the claim Role to the default claims, if i take it out it no longer shows. IT happens for every user including the admn default account.

The user store is a jdbc Mysql store
showing the list is fine
external AD user show fine as well from our secondary store
upgraded from wso2 identity 5.4.1 to 5.10.0

**Update:**
this only happens when i have the secondary user store of Active directory configured and of course the role claim supported by default, If i take the active dir secondary user store out then it works fine

This error show up as well in debug, we do not have anything like that Active dir configured though.

[2020-04-18 13:45:03,377] [] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Error occurred while getting user list from property : scimId & value : 25b4eba5-ca42-4af6-a0ff-f93fc9bef201 & profile name : null javax.naming.PartialResultException [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: **AuthLite.Masonite.com:389** [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out]]

Comment: Are you getting any error logs in wso2carbon.log? What is the userstore type now, UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager or JDBCUserStoreManager?

Comment: the same error as above shows whenever i change the role claim to supported by default. And yes in this version the jdbc is UniqueIDJDBCUserStoreManager. The odd thing is i can view the user roles in the admin just fine, this only happens when i click on the user profile

Comment: I just tried out in a 5.10.0 pack, but didn't get any issue. This could be due to an migration issue. Can you check for any error logs in wso2carbon.log?

Comment: this error happens first textPayload: "TID: [-1234] [2020-04-15 18:55:03,411] [173699ae-6b95-43b7-9cf7-fefbd0b0488e]  INFO {AUDIT_LOG} - Initiator=MASONITE/admin@carbon.super Action=Get-User-List Target=null Data={"Claim Value":"57e35821-eacd-4858-946a-8cdd64ad8197","Claim":"http://wso2.org/claims/userid"} Outcome=Failure Error={"Error Message":"Un-expected error while getting user list, Error occurred while getting user list from property : scimId & value : 57e35821-eacd-4858-946a-8cdd64ad8197 & profile name : null","Error Code":"34003"}

Comment: Need to check wso2carbon log for more info, not the audit log

Comment: actually what i did was just do a blank copy now with the jdbc pointed to a new schema from the zip. It still does the same thing, even without taking into account any migration

Comment: this is in the wsocarbon.log   - 2020-04-15 14:55:03.427 EDT
[2020-04-15 18:55:03,419] [173699ae-6b95-43b7-9cf7-fefbd0b0488e] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.ui.client.UserProfileCient} - org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.stub.UserProfileMgtServiceUserProfileExceptionException: UserProfileMgtServiceUserProfileExceptionException

Comment: image if the user-mgt.xml  https://pasteboard.co/J3XO5mR.png

Comment: i have narroed it down to now being an issue when adding a secondary user store of type activedir or ldap read only. So far i havent figured out why though, but if i remove this then it works to see the profile

Comment: this is where it errors, which doesn't make sense as this is not in our configs anywhere [2020-04-18 09:05:44,245] [] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager} - Error occurred while getting user list from property : scimId & value : 25b4eba5-ca42-4af6-a0ff-f93fc9bef201 & profile name : null javax.naming.PartialResultException [Root exception is javax.naming.CommunicationException: AuthLite.Masonite.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out]]   No idea where the AuthLite comes from